# Sum of a random variable and its own square

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation, integral-transforms

So I have the random variable $X$ in the following function:

$$ g(X) = \frac{X}{T}\left[ 1 + (X-1)\text{sinc}^{2}(fT) \right] $$

Expanding, gives us:

$$ g(X) = \frac{1 - \text{sinc}^{2}(fT)}{T}X + \frac{\text{sinc}^{2}(fT)}{T}X^{2} $$

How can I find the distribution of $Y = g(X)$, given that it is clearly not monotonic?

Note: My random variable $X$ can be Gamma, Erlang, or Chi distributed, and $f$ and $T$ are constants.

---

Edit: I remember something about using delta functions, but I cannot find the reference now...

Comment: Are $f$ and $T$ constants?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yes they are.

Comment: Write it as $aX^{2} + bX$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $a=\frac{\text{sinc}^2(fT)}{T}$  and $b=\frac{1-\text{sinc}^2(fT)}{T}$ . Suppose $X$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$ (which is the case for Chi-squared, Erlang, and Gamma distributions). Assume $a,b>0$ and fix $y\geq 0$. Notice $$aX^2+bX\leq y \iff X\in\Bigg[\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a},\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg]$$ Since $P\Bigg(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\leq X <0\Bigg)=0$ we have that $$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P\Bigg(X\leq\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)=F_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)$$ Hence $$f_Y(y)=f_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)\frac{d}{dy}\Bigg[\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg]=f_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}$$

On the other hand, if $a>0$ and $b<0$, we see $Y$ is supported on the interval $\big[-\frac{b^2}{4a},\infty\big)$. If $-\frac{b^2}{4a} \leq y \leq 0$ then

$$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P\Bigg(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a} \leq X \leq \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)=F_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)-F_X\Bigg(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)$$ Now if $y>0$ then

$$P(Y \leq y)=P\Bigg(X \leq \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a} \Bigg)=F_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)$$

So we get $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}\Bigg[f_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)+f_X\Bigg(\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)\Bigg] $$ whenever $-\frac{b^2}{4a} < y \leq 0$ and $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}f_X\Bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\Bigg)$$ whenever $y > 0$. Now let's consider the case when $a=0,b>0$. This is only possible if $Y=X/T$ which is supported on $[0,\infty)$ so for $y\geq 0$ we have $$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y \leq y)=P(X\leq Ty)=F_X(Ty)$$ This means $$f_Y(y)=f_X(Ty)\frac{d}{dy}\Big[Ty\Big]=Tf_X(Ty)$$ Lastly, if $a>0 \text{ and } b=0$, then $Y=X^2/T$ which is supported on $[0,\infty)$. So for $y \geq 0$ we have $$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y \leq y)=P\big(X^2 \leq Ty\big)=P\big(X \leq \sqrt{Ty}\big)=F_X\Big(\sqrt{Ty}\Big)$$ Finally, $$f_{Y}(y)=f_X\big(\sqrt{Ty}\big)\frac{d}{dy}\Big[\sqrt{Ty}\Big]=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{T}{y}}f_X\big(\sqrt{Ty}\big)$$ for $y>0$. All of these pdf's for $Y$ vanish elsewhere.

Comment: This is exactly what I found using the Dirac Delta method -- ( which I re-found the reference at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686109). Thank you so much for showing me the CDF version.

Comment: So it isn't the case that $a,b$>0, since the sinc function can be zero if I change f or T. I think this doesn't matter too much though, because we can define this case to drive the pdf or cdf to zero. Correct? Or am I wrong, and it will screw everything up? What happens when $f$ or $T$ is chosen such that we get zero for $a $ or $b$?

Comment: The coefficient $a$ can be $0$ and it can be negative. I'll show you how to proceed if $a<0$ in a moment. You need to be a little more careful.

Comment: I think you have switched the expressions $a$ and $b$. Ie $a$ should be $b$, and $b$ should be $a$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Is $ T$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Yes $T$ is positive.

Comment: I provided you the pdf for the case when $a>0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not sure where the claim of the support for Y comes from though....:-/

Comment: It's just a fancy way of saying that the range of $y=ax^2+bx$ is $[-b^2/4a,\infty)$ on the domain $x \geq 0$ whenever $a>0$ and $b<0$. Do you want me to also include the cases when $a>0,b=0$ and $a=0,b>0$?

Comment: Ah I see, okay. That would be great. It would make for a really good complete answer. I am sure that I am not the only one who has a quadratic function of their RV to work with.

Comment: If $a=0$ and $b>0$, then $bX \leq y$ which implies $X \leq \frac{y}{b}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, but if $a=0$, then $\text{sinh}^2(fT)=0$ which means $b=1/T$

Answer (score 0):

Since the coefficients on the $X$ and $X^2$ are constants, more generally, we can find the distribution of $$Y \sim aX^2+bX$$ The probability that $Y = y$ is given by the probability that $aX^2+bX = y$. This is equal to the probability that $aX^2+bX - y = 0 \to X = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}$. This means that the probability $Y = y$ is given by $$P\left(X=\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\right)+P\left(X=\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2+4ay}}{2a}\right)$$

Edit: The above probability would technically be $0$ for a continuous probability distribution for a given $y$. This is actually the PDF of $y$.

I wasn't being very mathematically rigorous previously, but the CDF would be $$P(Y < y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_Y(t) dt$$ where $f_Y(t)$ is the PDF of $Y$. The PDF is given by $P(Y=y)=f_Y(y)$.

Comment: The problems specifies that $X$ can be Gamma, Erlang, or Chi-squared, in which case $P(aX^2+bX=y)=0$.

Comment: @MatthewHolder I'm a bit confused by your comment. How would $X$ being gamma, Erlang, or chi-square distributed indicate that $P(Y=y)=0$? Are you saying that it equals $0$ for all $y$ or just some subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If, for example, $X$ possessed a Gamma distribution, then $aX^2+bX$ is a continuous random variable, which implies $P(aX^2+bX=y)=0$ for every $y$. Same goes for Chi squared and Erlang.

Comment: @MatthewHolder I see what you are saying, but in a continuous probability distribution, the probability of $X$ being any specific value would be $0$. The end result from using the CDF $P(Y \le y)$ and then differentiating to get the PDF would be the same, so I just skipped that step.

Comment: The outputs of the pdf for a continuous random variable don't represent probability, but probability *density*. For example, if $X \sim N(0,0.01)$ then $f_X(x)=\frac{10}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-50x^2}$ is the pdf for $X$. Notice $f_X(0)=\frac{10}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is larger than $1$, so it cannot possibly represent $P(X=0)$.

Comment: @MatthewHolder I had made an edit that I thought explained this. Does the edit clarify this for you?